# How can I only return document specific fields from Firebase SDK?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

is there a way with Firestore to only return specific fields, like `collection('colA').select('fieldA').get()`, but from a React Native client to save on bandwidth?

PS: I am aware of select() with the NodeJS SDK but it's not our use case

Comment: The client SDKs do not support it yet. The REST API might be useful but its not as convenient as the SDKs

Comment: Hi @Dharmaraj, thanks for your answer, when you say "yet" is it something you know they have on their roadmap?